# Dynamic rails selection/dropdowns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I'm trying to make a form with two selects. When user selects from the first select Category, another one should automatically be updated and show SubCategories according to Category.

I made ajax call with *remote_function*, and on Category select it calls for get_subcategories from items controller. It works :) But the partial does not show select...I'm trying different ways, but every time I get an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `all' for nil:NilClass):
```

Here is get_subcategories in in items controller, it calls for the partial _subcategory_dropdown:

```
 def get_subcategories
    subcategories = SubCategory.find_by_category_id(params[:category_id])
    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html 'subcategory_dropdown', :partial => 'subcategories', :locals => { :object => subcategories }
    end
  end
```

and here is an extract from _subcategory_dropdown partial:

```
 select(:category_id, subcategories.all.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, {:include_blank => true})
```

any ideas?

Comment: try making subcategories public (like @subcategories)...

Comment: I think this tutorial is something similar of what your trying to do http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus?autoplay=true hope it gives you some idea even if not exactly but to some extent

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [blog article](http://homeonrails.blogspot.com/2012/01/rails-31-linked-dropdown-cascading.html) - it demonstrates a nice easy way to do linked dropdowns in Rails 3.1.